# Search API: snippeted_fields option return error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'prev_len' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, full-text-search

I'm using a "snippeted_fields" in GAE search api to search a product description.

This is the Product Description in the Search index table : **Multirate 10G IP Services Engine (Modular)+Phone**. And i'm searching for **Multirate 10G IP**. No Error in appspot. But dev_appserver return following error.

```
ERROR    2012-10-03 04:22:40,497 functions.py:143] local variable 'prev_len' referenced before assignment
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
     rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
     return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
     return handler.dispatch()
   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
     return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
     return method(*args, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\app_search\search.py", line 1664, in get
     result = find_search_document(search_item)
   File "C:\Users\app_search\search.py", line 192, in find_search_document
     result = index.search(query_string)
   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\search\search.py", line 2722, in search
     apiproxy_stub_map.MakeSyncCall('search', 'Search', request, response)
   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 94, in MakeSyncCall
     return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 320, in MakeSyncCall
     rpc.CheckSuccess()
   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_rpc.py", line 156, in _WaitImpl
     self.request, self.response)
   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub.py", line 160, in MakeSyncCall
    method(request, response)
   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\search\simple_search_stub.py", line 871, in _Dynamic_Search
     results = index.Search(params)
   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\search\simple_search_stub.py", line 510, in Search
     docs = self._AttachExpressions(docs, search_request)
   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\search\simple_search_stub.py", line 493, in _AttachExpressions
     evaluator.Evaluate(expr)
   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\search\stub\expression_evaluator.py", line 198, in Evaluate
    result = self._Eval(expression_tree)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\search\stub\expression_evaluator.py", line 156, in _Eval
    return func(*node.children)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\search\stub\expression_evaluator.py", line 132, in _Snippet
    doc_words, position, search_util.DEFAULT_MAX_SNIPPET_LENGTH)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\search\stub\expression_evaluator.py", line 95, in _GenerateSnippet
    while (len(snippet) + next_len + prev_len + 6 < max_length and
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'prev_len' referenced before assignment
```

Code:

```
def find_search_document(query):
   _INDEX_NAME = "GPL_Description"    
   query = '"{0}"'.format(query.replace('"',''))

   options = search.QueryOptions(           
        snippeted_fields=['description'])

   query_string = search.Query(query_string = query, options = options)

   index = search.Index(name=_INDEX_NAME)
   return index.search(query_string)
```

Also Is that possible to highlight the search query for small description like "Multirate 10G IP Services Engine" using search api?

Answer (score 2):

IIRC **snippeted_fields** do not work on the dev server.

Try deploying it and checking the behaviour, it should work as expected when deployed.

Although in my experience it just returns no results on the dev server rather then the error you have above.

Comment: Okay.But dev_server returning error. And in deployed app the query string is not highlighted. It is showing in the normal case.

Comment: Ensure that you are rendering the string as "safe", I get out the result with the keyword in bold via <strong> tags IIRC. It does work.